# MySQL COUNT() causing empty array() return

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**MySQL Server Version:** Server version: 4.1.14

**MySQL client version:** 3.23.49

**Tables under discussion:** ads_list and ads_cate.

**Table Relationship:** ads_cate has many ads_list.

**Keyed by:** ads_cate.id = ads_list.Category.

I am not sure what is going on here, but I am trying to use COUNT() in a simple agreggate query, and I get blank output.

Here is a simple example, this returns expected results:

```
$queryCats = "SELECT id, cateName FROM ads_cate ORDER BY cateName";
```

But if I modify it to add the COUNT() and the other query data I get no array return w/ print_r() (no results)?

```
$queryCats = "SELECT ads_cate.cateName, ads_list.COUNT(ads_cate.id), 
FROM ads_cate INNER JOIN ads_list 
ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
GROUP BY cateName ORDER BY cateName";
```

Ultimately, I am trying to get a count of ad_list items in each category.

Is there a MySQL version conflict on what I am trying to do here?

NOTE: I spent some time breaking this down, item by item and the COUNT() seems to cause the array() to disappear. And the the JOIN seemed to do the same thing... It does not help I am developing this on a Yahoo server with no access to the php or mysql error settings.

Comment: It should be SELECT ads_cate.cateName, COUNT(ads_cate.id),

Comment: I updated my answer to your other question.

Comment: Given the sql syntax error with `ads_list.COUNT(...)`, you're probably not checking for sql error conditions after doing the query. Somethign like `$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` would scream about the error right away, rather than silently covering it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$queryCats = "SELECT ads_cate.cateName, COUNT(ads_cate.id) 
              FROM ads_cate
              JOIN ads_list ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category
              GROUP BY ads_cate.cateName";
```

I am guessing that you need the category to be in the list, in that case the query here should work. Try it without the ORDER BY first.

Comment: ersamy, I think this did the trick. I am finally getting array output and I did add the ORDER BY with no issues:     [cateName] => Computers / Laptops
    [COUNT(ads_list.Title)] => 11

Comment: I should note I changed the COUNT to COUNT(ads_list.Title) to get a Title count of items in ads_list.

Comment: @OldWest: See Carlos Cocom's answer which explains why `COUNT(ads_list.Title)` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think your COUNT syntax is wrong.  It should be:

`COUNT(ads_cate.id)`

or

`COUNT(ads_list.id)`

depending on what you are counting.

Comment: Mike, I tried that earlier. Makes no difference. The array() is non existent either way. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @OldWest: I'm not sure what array you are referring to.  However, I suspect that your existing query will be throwing an error, which might be the problem.  You also have a comma after the COUNT (before FROM), which may also be throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

Count is an aggregate. means ever return result set at least one

here you be try count ads_list.id not null but that wrong. how say Myke Count(ads_cate.id) or Count(ads_list.id) is better approach

you have inner join ads_cate.id = ads_list.category so Count(ads_cate.id) or COUNT(ads_list.id) is not necessary just count(*)

now if you dont want null add having

only match

```
SELECT ads_cate.cateName, COUNT(*), 
FROM ads_cate INNER JOIN ads_list 
ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
GROUP BY cateName 
having not count(*) is null
ORDER BY cateName
```

all

```
SELECT ads_cate.cateName, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0), 
FROM ads_cate LEFT JOIN ads_list 
ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
GROUP BY cateName    
ORDER BY cateName
```

Comment: Carlos, I get no array returned with with of these. I should also note I have triple and double checked all of my field names and table names for typos.

Comment: Maybe the problem is datatype return by mysql try use Format in column count. something how that FORMAT(COUNT(*),0) As hits

Answer (score 1):

You were probably getting errors. Check your server logs.

Also, see what happens when you try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), category 
FROM ads_list 
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "ORDER BY should come before GROUP BY". Please review or will be most likely downvoted

Comment: Jacob, this returns an array.

Comment: Any empty array? Or one with the proper counts?

Answer (score 1):

Your array is empty or disappear because your query has errors:

1. there should be no comma before the FROM
2. the "ads_list." prefix before COUNT is incorrect

Please try running that query directly in MySQL and you'll see the errors. Or try echoing the output using mysql_error().

Now, some other points related to your query:

1. there is no need to do ORDER BY because GROUP BY by default sorts on the grouped column
2. you are doing a count on the wrong column that will always give you 1

Perhaps you are trying to retrieve the count of ads_list per ads_cate? This might be your query then:

```
SELECT `ads_cate`.`cateName`, COUNT(`ads_list`.`category`) `cnt_ads_list`
FROM `ads_cate`
INNER JOIN `ads_list` ON `ads_cate`.`id` = `ads_list`.`category`
GROUP BY `cateName`;
```

Hope it helps?

Comment: Yes helps very much for clarification thank you. Now if I can just figure out how to echo the count value I will be set. I am trying this echo $category['COUNT(Title)'] but no value..

Comment: @OldWest: I guess that might not be the right way. Give your COUNT column an alias, say `cnt`, like in the query in my response. Then do `$category['cnt']`, where I assume $category is where you are fetching into your MySQL resultset

Comment: I was able to get it working by doing this: $category['COUNT(ads_list.Title)'] and in my query this: COUNT(ads_list.Title)